# Softmax layer, for discriminative restricted Boltzmann machine

Tags: deep-learning, softmax

1. I'm using 4 layers of RBMs to create a DBN. (each layer has 21 nodes)
2. At the last layer, I'm adding label data, specifically, 2 classes.(This DBN is a binary clasifier. After adding class label data, I have 21+2=23 nodes in the top layer).
3. I'm softmax-ing the outputs of the last layer, combined with class label inputs, to a 2-cell vector.(a 1 in location 0 indicates class 0, 1 in location 1 indicates class 1).

Questions - 
1. Does this softmax layer need to be trained, with CD-k? Meaning, do I need to CD between the output layer and last(augmented) layer?

2. How does one initialise the weights for the last layer-to-output layer connections?
3. Alternatively, does one need to train the top layer, now  21+2 units with CD-k against the lower layer?

Thanks. 
I'm looking at this paper - http://machinelearning.org/archive/icml2008/papers/601.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you use CD to train the target label and the input feature jointly as the visible layer data in the RBM.
2. It is randomly initialized, your "last-to-output" weight matrix is part of the top layer RBM weight matrix. As shown in the figure in the paper, {x,y} can be seen as a single visible layer of a RBM.
3. So training this {x,y}-h RBM is same as you train an ordinary v-h RBM.

Finally if you want a separate softmax layer, you ara actually looking for a DNN, which can be initialized by the DBN you are training here. But that's another story.

---

For 2-class classification, you could either use 2 nodes with 1-of-2 coding softmax layer, or 1 binary node (0 for one class, 1 for the other).

Comment: Thanks very much, Yin. Just a few clarifications - 
 1. So then, the output layer(which is NOT the softmax layer), will be a CD between (21+2) and (1) nodes? I'm assuming (2) nodes for class labels, because a 1 in the index location will indicate the class. (1 in 0 means class 0, and so on)
2. Not meaning to hair-split, so then, the final output layer just adds one(1) node, for the class label, not two? 
3. And when doing a CD, I'm training jointly, for all 23, not 21 and 2 separately, correct?

Comment: for point 3, yes. for others - I don't understand you. you may want to give more detail about the structure of your DBN - how each layer is connected. Is it {x,y}-h1-h2-h3, where x is feature vector, y is label vector, h? are hidden layers, or is it x-h1-h2-h3-y, and {y,h2} is the visible layer of the top RBM {y,h2}-h3

Comment: My bad, let me clarify - I'm adding the label vector only in the end, at the last layer. So I start with x, then go to h1, then h2, then h3. That makes 3 hidden layers. At h3, I concatenate labels(2 node vector, in this case). That makes h3 have (h3+2) nodes. Then the h3+2 nodes all present their outputs to one output node, which is the classifier output.  I CD between all layers. Even the top layer - which is (h3+2) and (output) , they get a CD too.

Comment: Also, (I just read your edit, I could use the 1-of-2 coding layer too for the classification, I have code for that commented out right now) - thanks once again.

Comment: Also, at the top layer, ((h3+2) and (output)), I'm using the equation for p(y given x) that is at the bottom right of page 2 of this paper, for classification - http://machinelearning.org/archive/icml2008/papers/601.pdf . Just thought I'd mention that too.

Comment: i'm not sure if you are using the same way as in that paper. anyway the way in the paper is old, now DNN is the standard way for classification.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm using the approach that Hinton et al used, as explained in his lectures, adding label information at the very last. The paper, I understand, sends in label information at the input layer itself. This would then model joint probabilities of x and y across all layers.